# Extract list for each row in panda dataframe while removing nans

Tags: python, pandas

Quite similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424687/how-to-make-list-of-lists-from-pandas-dataframe-skipping-nan-values) here

Having a dataframe

```
                 COL_A    ...    COL G   ...      COL N
0                 NaN  ...        Nan    ...        wds
1                 NaN  ...        Nan    ...        dst
2                 ds  ...         Nan    ...        NaN
3                 NaN  ...        Nan    ...        NaN
```

I would like to extract list of lists (or numpy array , dont mind) as following:

`l = [['wds'],['dst],['dst'] , [] ]` ,i.e

```
len(l) == df.shape[0]
```

When trying things like :

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).tolist()
Out[]: [['wds'],['dst'],['dst']]
```

The all-nan rows are being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
L = df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1).tolist()
print (L)
[['wds'], ['dst'], ['ds'], []]
```

Comment: any idea how to add the column name into that list ,like [[COL N:wds],[COL N:wds] , [COL_A: ds] , [ ] ]